# Is it possible to deploy .net core web api to vercel?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, vercel

I just created a sample .net core web api project in order to learn. Api has two endpoints (get and post data)

Is it possible to deploy this web api to vercel ?

I also created the node.js version of this project and it is very easy to deploy it on vercel,  but couldn't find a way to deploy .net core web api to vercel.app ?

Here is the vercel.json configuration file that i last tried :

```
{
"version": 2,
"builds": [
  {
    "src": "publish/**/*.dll",
    "use": "@vercel/dotnet"
  }
],
"routes": [
  {
    "src": "/api/data/:collectionName",
    "dest": "/api/data/:collectionName"
  },
  {
    "src": "/(.*)",
    "dest": "/index.html"
  }
]
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Vercel does not support a runtime for .net.
Here is a list of supported frameworks: https://vercel.com/docs/frameworks/more-frameworks

But you can create your own community runtime.
Vercel has more information at this link [Choosing a Runtime](https://vercel.com/docs/functions)

Also, as a heads up Vercel does not support Docker containers or container
deployments in general.

Alternatively you could host your .Net backend on AWS or Azure and then host the
front end of your app on Vercel but you would have to create the front end with a supported framework like Nuxt or Next js.

The process of creating your own community runtime is quite complex and there is not much guidance or documentation.

But this article outlines how you could potentially configure the build for
your .NET application
[Configure Vercel Build for .NET](https://vercel.com/docs/functions/configuring-functions/runtime#other-runtimes)
Using this approach you only have to tweak the build configuration and a few other things. No community runtime required

You might run into a couple of problems here though. One being that the build
process cannot find the application. You'll have to add the right path to your
application.
**dotnet run --project name-of-your-project-here**

You can find more information about configuring your build at these links:

[Vercel Functions](https://vercel.com/docs/functions)

[Configuring Runtimes for Vercel Functions](https://vercel.com/docs/functions/configuring-functions/runtime#other-runtimes)
[Configuring Projects with json](https://vercel.com/docs/projects/project-configuration#functions)

Here are some discussion threads on Github but there are no answers unfortunately.
Here is a link to some guidance on community runtime setup:
[Developing a Community Runtime](https://github.com/vercel/vercel/blob/main/DEVELOPING_A_RUNTIME.md)

Here is a link to someone asking a similar question to you:
[enter link description here](https://github.com/orgs/vercel/discussions/2827)

Here is a link to another similar question:
[enter link description here](https://github.com/orgs/vercel/discussions/1392)

Answer (score -1):

After doing some research, I think it's impossible to deploy the .net/.net core application to `vercel`.

[List of supported frameworks](https://vercel.com/docs/frameworks#list-of-supported-frameworks)

[image]

Comment: Vercel does not support the .Net framework. If you look through the list of supported frameworks and read this post https://github.com/orgs/vercel/discussions/2827 you'll see that

Comment: @TheHollyRoller Noted, https://github.com/vercel/vercel/blob/main/DEVELOPING_A_RUNTIME.md#supporting-large-environment